# Could the 'air conditioner' shown here be run during shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology

I saw this DIY video, and was wondering if such a fan could be run before shabbat started and left running as shown?

The video on this page (Ignore the article):

http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/gadgets/home/dyson-bladeless-fan.htm

Question is in theory only, I have no plans on building such a fan.

Original link was based on the following embed code:

> iframe id="dit-video-embed" width="384" height="216"
>   src="http://static.discoverymedia.com/videos/components/hsw/30113-title/snag-it-player.html?auto=no"
>   frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true">

Comment: Your link doesn't work...

Comment: Would this plan require refilling the water tank?

Comment: yydl, good question. I'm not sure :)  Maybe assume yes, no, and only refilling it before it's empty?

Comment: Basically the apparatus circulates what starts as ice water round a fan inside copper tubing. The water is not used up. It will of course slowly get warmer and end up at room temperature. I see no issur shabbos as long as the fan was started before Shabbos. Am I missing somnething?

Comment: The water goes into the plants after being sucked up by the fan. Or atleast, something wet goes into the plants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your concern is the watering of the plants that will occur during Shabbos, that is not a problem, since the system was set up before Shabbos. This is taught explicitly in Shabbos 18a regarding the similar case of opening a water channel into a garden before Shabbos. Refilling the reservoir on Shabbos is a more difficult question, and probably depends on whether the watering of the plants is a certainty (פסיק רישא), and whether the person cares or benefits from the watering.

Comment: According to that video, they obviously do not care to water the plants, they just don't want the water 'in the house'.  There is a small chance that the pipe has a leak and not all the water will go directly to the plants.. It is a DIY project :)
Does it matter if they refill the water before it empties out?